# onchange of javascript filled in field issue

Tags: javascript, onchange

I want to use `onchange()` event on a text field that may be filled in by a date picker using javascript. i tried to use `onblur()`, `onmouseover()` and etc but non of them can help me to catch its value just after changing by date picker.
a part of code that defined date picker and fill in text field is like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/cal_.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="receive_date" id="receive_date" style="width:75px" class="cdate" value="" {{attributes}}>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new LCalendar('receive_date');
</script>
```

but when I want to add `onchange="_do_something()"` in place of `{{attributes}}` it does not work.

Comment: Check the datapicker API to see if it provides a callback when the user selects a date.

Comment: Dear Barmar, i use a Localized datepicker that does not provide any callback in case of date selection. also please note that there is no problem in datepicker and filling in text field. just when i want to catch changed value onchange this field it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for good answers.
After testing so many solutions i changed my calendar library code.
Just after filling in date (text) field in code:

```
receive_date_field.value=...;
```

I tried to put:

```
a.focus();
a.blur();
```

twice and for catching its value after every filling in (either by another javascript code) i used:

```
onfocus="_do_something();"
```

in place of `{{attributes}}` !!! as you see this is not what i want but just is a temporary way to catch value of field after every filling in.

Answer (score 0):

The text input is don't have change event. the event you can use to get the input change is to use 'input'. see sample

```
inputVar.addEventListener('input', function(){'what you want to do.'});
```

Comment: Text input fields certainly _do_ have a `change` event. It's triggered when you modify the field and then blur out of it.

Comment: Is true by W3C but make problems in some platforms. as you can see.

Comment: yes Barmar it is ... but what should i do in case of change its value by another event using javascript...

Comment: Events like `change` and `input` are only triggered by user actions. That's why most widgets provide their own events that you can use. If your datepicker doesn't provide any way to do this, I don't know of a solution. If it's a locally-written datepicker, you need to improve it.

Comment: thanks Barmar. my localized calendar .js code is a generic class that is used in many projects and i can not add any methods to it for a special case!

Comment: The input event is triggering also if the input change without user action. 
user, did you mean you cannot assign function via event listener just via embed attribute on HTML element?

Comment: Dear manor, as you can see in code i want to catch such an event by filling in {{attributes}} in field code. but onchange does not work... also you can simply test such a situation by defining two text fields that on change value of field A same go to field B and onchange value of field B try to do something.... onchange does not work for second step...

Comment: If i understand you right so you want to assign to element attribute onchange to call external function. so you cannot cause onchange event is firing just when have user action. you need to use 'input' event. if you cannot using addEventListener because your class is dynamically so you can put some custom data attribute such a data-change="true" and call the input by the data attribute in external JS code.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplistic, but you could try this:

```
var val;

document.getElementById('receive_date').addEventListener('focus', function() {
    // set the value
    val = this.value;
});

document.getElementById('receive_date').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if (this.value !== val) {
        // val was changed
    } else {
        // val was not changed
    }
});
```